# CSV Import task status in Netsuite

Tags: csv, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am creating a task using the Scriptlet as below and submitting the task. This task may need 30 Sec to 5 min for completion. Now once I submit the job I dont have a control except the task id. I want to know the status or the message once the cob is finished or completed.

```
var cvsScriptTask = task.create({
        taskType : task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT ,
        mappingId : cvsTask.mappingId ,
        importFile : cvsFileObj ,
        name : cvsFileObj.name ,
    });
var csvImportTaskId = cvsScriptTask.submit();
```

Can I get the status of this task/job from some table/record ?

Comment: I always find that checking the status isnt very useful since imports either 100% succeed or fail so if it fails netsuite sends you an email straightaway. If you get the id it means it completed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Setup>Import/Export>View CSV Import Status

Comment: Yes. Thats what ... But how to read the same data using Scriptlet.
I am setting the job through the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to read the information. You can use nlapiSetRedirectURL, so the user will be redirected to the page.

Comment: I am trying to download the result from Job Status page. The URL looks like as below.

**system.na2.netsuite.com/app/setup/upload/csv/uploadlogcsv.nl?wqid=10571**

But I am not able to figure out the wqid. I belive that its a job id. 
But the task return a big string of job id which does not match or comes near to this.... 
:(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the task status programmatically by using the N/task module and call `task.checkStatus(taskID)`. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4345805891.html

Note that status `COMPLETE` only means that the CSV Import is done, not that it was successful. To see if all rows were imported you need to either check the UI Setup>Import/Export>View CSV Import Status (like @vVinceth suggested) or you can use SuiteQL to query `SentEmail` and parse the text in that email…

And even if you do find the `SentEmail` for the corresponding CSV Import it still doesn't say *why* some rows failed. That information is *only* available via the UI as far as I know. Very frustrating!